# What is the resolution of the stars of the RatingBar?

Tags: android, ratingbar

I want to recreate the stars for my custom rating bar to ensure proper scaling, I was using the dfault android one because it scalled a lot better on higher resolution devices. However, it's ugly, so I want to try and fix my custom rating bar. All I want to know is the resolution of the stars on the default android RatingBar.

Answer (score 0):

50px x 50px worked for my custom buttons.